# className Changing not passing through all if and else if Statements

Tags: javascript, css, class, getelementbyid, classname

Having an issue with changing classes. I can get it to work if I hardcode pixels into the style change but wanted a cleaner version using classes and CSS. The goal is to have the pixel change sizes larger and smaller due to the value of healthPercent in width. This part works but the trouble part is changing the classes to change the color of the bar. For some reason, it does not pass through the if statements correctly and just stays green until death (zero or less for healthPercent), when it reaches zero and then turns red. I can't quite figure out why it passes through the first if check but not the rest. Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: I'm working on a game. just to clarify.

JAVASCRIPT

```
displayLifeBar = function ()
{


    pixelMod = 2.3; //added definition here but global on full code
    healthPercent = 130; //added here for example but passed down
    lifeBar = 'player_lifebar';


    document.getElementById(lifeBar).style.width = healthPercent + 'px';

    var criticalLife = 25 * pixelMod;
    var lowLife = 50 * pixelMod;
    var hurtLife = 75 * pixelMod;

    if (healthPercent <= 0){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = '';
    }        
    else if (healthPercent < criticalLife){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar critical';
    }
    else if (healthPercent < lowLife){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar low';
    }    
    else if (healthPercent < hurtLife){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar hurt';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar';
    }
}
```

CSS

```
/* LIFEBAR COLORS STARTS */

.lifebar{
    height:20px;
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
.lifebar.hurt{
    background-color: gold;
}
.lifebar.low{
    background-color: orange;
}
.lifebar.critical{
    background-color: red;
}
/* LIFEBAR COLORS ENDS */
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, specially `just stays green until death, when it reaches zero and then turns red`.

Comment: Working for me. Might wanna post the relevent HTML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet seems to be working from what you described - assuming your HTML just looks like `<div id='player_lifebar'></div>`.

```js
var pixelMod = 2.3;
var healthPercent = 10;
var lifeBar = 'player_lifebar';

displayLifeBar = function ()
{
    document.getElementById(lifeBar).style.width = healthPercent + 'px';

    var criticalLife = 25 * pixelMod;
    var lowLife = 50 * pixelMod;
    var hurtLife = 75 * pixelMod;

    if (healthPercent <= 0){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = '';
    } else if (healthPercent < criticalLife){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar critical';
    } else if (healthPercent < lowLife){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar low';
    }  else if (healthPercent < hurtLife){
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar hurt';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(lifeBar).className = 'lifebar';
    }
}

displayLifeBar();


// for testing:
function modifyHealth(points) {
  healthPercent = healthPercent + points;
  displayLifeBar(); //re-render healthbar
}

document.getElementById('heal').addEventListener('click', function() { modifyHealth(10) });
document.getElementById('attack').addEventListener('click', function() { modifyHealth(-10) });
```

```css
.lifebar{
    height:20px;
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
.lifebar.hurt{
    background-color: gold;
}
.lifebar.low{
    background-color: orange;
}
.lifebar.critical{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='player_lifebar'></div>
<!-- for testing -->
<br>
<button id='heal'>♡ heal (+10)</button>
<button id='attack'> attack (-10)</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for running the code, I must be looking at the wrong area. I'll check the HTML side. Nice little testing code, I was messing around with pushing the buttons back and forth for quite a bit lol. I think I will simplify the rest of my code much more just from seeing that.